# Google Web App onload script not working on HTML output

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-apps-script

I have a code.gs file serving an HTML file, which contains an onload function and also a button triggering another function in the same file. When I click on the button, the onclick event is not triggered, and also the onload function does not trigger when the web app is accessed.

```
    function doGet() {

   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)  
html.setWidth(800);
  html.setHeight(400);



  return html;
}

function populate1(){


  //CHANGE spreadsheet ID
var a = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ea4hkN48Tu9M9y03e_Xrxp_s8hk882UzzOVtk4HVRlE");

  //sheets
  var ERsheet = a.getSheetByName("Equipment request");
  var TRsheet = a.getSheetByName("Troubleshooting");
  var OTsheet = a.getSheetByName("Other requests");

  //lrs
  var ERlr = ERsheet.getLastRow();
  var TRlr = TRsheet.getLastRow();
  var OTlr = OTsheet.getLastRow();

  //lrs 2
  var ERlr2 = (ERsheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  var TRlr2 = (TRsheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  var OTlr2 = (OTsheet.getLastRow() - 1);

  //lrs 3
  var ERlr3 = (ERsheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  var TRlr3 = (TRsheet.getLastRow() - 2);
  var OTlr3 = (OTsheet.getLastRow() - 2);



  //copyranges

  //ER
  var ERcro11 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var ERcro12 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var ERcro13 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var ERcrd1 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
  var ERcro21 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var ERcro22 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr2, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var ERcro23 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr2, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var ERcrd2 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr2, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
  var ERcro31 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr3, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var ERcro32 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr3, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var ERcro33 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr3, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var ERcrd3 = ERsheet.getRange(ERlr3, 5, 1, 1).getValue();

  //TR
  var TRcro11 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var TRcro12 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var TRcro13 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var TRcr1 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
  var TRcro21 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var TRcro22 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr2, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var TRcro23 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr2, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var TRcr2 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr2, 5, 1, 1).getValue();
  var TRcro31 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr3, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var TRcro32 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr3, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var TRcro33 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr3, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var TRcr3 = TRsheet.getRange(TRlr3, 5, 1, 1).getValue();

  //OT
  var OTcro1 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var OTcro1 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var OTcro1 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var OTcr1 = TRsheet.getRange(OTlr, 5, 1, 1).getValue(); 
  var OTcro2 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr2, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var OTcro2 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr2, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var OTcro2 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr2, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var OTcr2 = TRsheet.getRange(OTlr2, 5, 1, 1).getValue();   
  var OTcro3 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr3, 1, 1, 1).getValue();
   var OTcro3 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr3, 2, 1, 1).getValue();
    var OTcro3 = OTsheet.getRange(OTlr3, 3, 1, 1).getValue();
     var OTcr3 = TRsheet.getRange(OTlr3, 5, 1, 1).getValue(); 


  var g = 0;
  //JSONArray jsarray = new JSONArray();

// var json = [
 //  {"ERc1c1":ERcro11, "ERc1c2":ERcrd1}, 
 //   {"ERc2c1":ERcro21, "ERc2c2":ERcrd2}, 
 //   {"ERc3c1":ERcro31, "ERc3c2":ERcrd3}
 //  ];


  return (ERcro11, ERcro12, ERcro13, ERcrd1,
          ERcro21, ERcro22, ERcro23, ERcrd2,
          ERcro31, ERcro32, ERcro33, ERcrd3);





      }
```

the code serves Index.HTML, which is the file below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<style> 
tablestats{
align: right;
right-padding: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}
body{
border: 5px;

}

</style>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad">
</script>
    <script>
function filler1(ERcro11, ERcro12, ERcro13, ERcrd1,
          ERcro21, ERcro22, ERcro23, ERcrd2,
          ERcro31, ERcro32, ERcro33, ERcrd3){






//dates
//var date1 = document.getElementByID("date1").innerHTML = ERcro11;
//var date2 = document.getElementByID("date2").innerHTML = ERcro21;
//var date3 = document.getElementByID("date3").innerHTML = ERcro31;
//var date4 = document.getElementByID("date4").innerHTML = ;
//var date5 = document.getElementByID("date5").innerHTML = ;
//var date6 = document.getElementByID("date6").innerHTML = ;
//var date7 = document.getElementByID("date7").innerHTML = ;
//var date8 = document.getElementByID("date8").innerHTML = ;
//var date9 = document.getElementByID("date9").innerHTML = ;

//senders
//var sender1 = document.getElementByID("sender1").innerHTML = ERcro12;
//var sender2 = document.getElementByID("sender2").innerHTML = ERcro22;
//var sender3 = document.getElementByID("sender3").innerHTML = ERcro32;
//var sender4 = document.getElementByID("sender4").innerHTML = ;
//var sender5 = document.getElementByID("sender5").innerHTML = ;
//var sender6 = document.getElementByID("sender6").innerHTML = ;
//var sender7 = document.getElementByID("sender7").innerHTML = ;
//var sender8 = document.getElementByID("sender8").innerHTML = ;
//var sender9 = document.getElementByID("sender9").innerHTML = ;

//types
//var type1 = document.getElementByID("type1").innerHTML = ERcrd1;
//var type2 = document.getElementByID("type2").innerHTML = ERcrd2;
//var type3 = document.getElementByID("type3").innerHTML = ERcrd3;
//var type4 = document.getElementByID("type4").innerHTML = ;
//var type5 = document.getElementByID("type5").innerHTML = ;
//var type6 = document.getElementByID("type6").innerHTML = ;
//var type7 = document.getElementByID("type7").innerHTML = ;
//var type8 = document.getElementByID("type8").innerHTML = ;
//var type9 = document.getElementByID("type9").innerHTML = ;

//duedates
document.getElementByID("request1").innerHTML = "hola";
//var duedate2 = document.getElementByID("request2").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate3 = document.getElementByID("request3").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate4 = document.getElementByID("request4").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate5 = document.getElementByID("request5").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate6 = document.getElementByID("request6").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate7 = document.getElementByID("request7").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate8 = document.getElementByID("request8").innerHTML = ;
//var duedate9 = document.getElementByID("request9").innerHTML = ;


}

function trigger(){

google.script.run.withsuccesshandler(filler1).populate1();



}

function testfunc(){

document.getElementByID("date1").innerHTML = "test";


}


<?!= include('script_js'); ?>
</script>
  </head>



  <body onload="testfunc()">


<table width="40%" class="tablestats">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date1">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender1">x</td><td class="Type" id="type1" >x</td><td class="due date1" id="request1">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date2">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender2">x</td><td class="Type" id="type2" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request2">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date3">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender3">x</td><td class="Type" id="type3" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request3">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date4">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender4">x</td><td class="Type" id="type4" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request4">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date5">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender5">x</td><td class="Type" id="type5" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request5">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date6">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender6">x</td><td class="Type" id="type6" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request6">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date7">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender7">x</td><td class="Type" id="type7" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request7">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date8">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender8">x</td><td class="Type" id="type8" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request8">x</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="Date" id="date9">x</td><td class="sender" id="sender9">x</td><td class="Type" id="type9" >x</td><td class="due date" id="request9">x</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
<!--<input type="button" onclick="testfunc()"> Populate </input> -->
<button onclick="testfunc()">Click me</button>



  </body>
</html>
```

Do I need a DoPost(e) function in my code.gs file? I don't understand why script files set inside the HTML file are not being run even when called by onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a doPost(e) just to run what is basically AJAX. You need to use google script runners in order for your client side script to communicate with your apps script.

Here is the reference about [Client-Server Communication in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).